# Making a video element with no sound accessible

Tags: html, accessibility

I am currently working on a web page with a *silent* video banner.

I am using the [aXe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd) Chrome browser plugin that highlights potential accessibility issues with the content of the page and it's throwing two issues related accessibility for the video element:

- Ensure `<video>` elements have captions
- Ensure `<video>` elements have audio descriptions

I just wanted to know if there are any recommendations in communicating that the video element has no audio in an accessible way.

Comment: Yes, you can check whether the video has audio or not using html5 audio/ video volume control.Hope this helps, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_muted    and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_volume

Comment: As I understand the question, the point isn't checking that the video has audio or not, that's a fact: the video has no audio.
The goal is rather to indicate that fact in some accessible way

Comment: That's correct @QuentinC. I could probably add an descriptive audio track but really after guidance on how best to say there is no audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`video` accessibility has two concerns : captions for replacing sound, and audio decription (or textual alternatives) for describing the images.

The fact that your video is silent does not mean that you do not need a textual description of what appears in the video.

1. In your case, I would look at the attribute `controls="muted"` which can be an hint for indicating assistive technologies that a video does not have currently any sound.
2. I will choose between one of the following:

   a) I will set the `aria-describedby` attribute on the `video` element to point to the `div` containing the description.

   b) OR If your video is only decorative, then I would set the `aria-hidden=true` attribute on a parent element

Comment: IF the video is decorative, I would say aria-hidden=true rather than role=presentation. There is almost no interest to fill the buffer of screen readers with contents that are anyway totally uninteresting. Addiitionally, role=presentation basicly means "this element has no role" or "remove the default role this element should normally have". Put on the parent of the video, probably a div or something similar with no semantic significance, it won't have any effect.

Comment: @QuentinC The `aria-hidden` attribute should be privilleged to information not visible to any user (and not only to information not visible by AT users). The inheritance of the `presentation` role is quite hard to understand (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation) and seems to apply only to *required owned elements* which does not include the `video` element. For that reason, I change in favor of the `aria-hidden` attribute but i would rather have set the `presentation` role on the `video` element if it had been possible, like for `img` elements.

Comment: A decorative video without sound is totally uninteresting for a screen reader user anyway, so better is not to pollute uselessly the read information. I'm screen reader user myself, so I can tell you; that's the same as line numbers for code snippets. Look also at the techniques used to use text-based icons and you will see in that case that aria-hidden is applied to something visible to normal users but should be hidden to screen readers. For me that would be the same here if the video is effectively decorative.

Comment: @QuentinC The difficult aspect is that `aria-hidden` will remove the element from any assistive technology. For instance, an eye tracking device might need to activate the play/pause button even though the media is purely decorative. But I agree perfectly that in the current usage of ARIA, `aria-hidden` is better than `presentation` role.